# Tell Visual Studio Code suggestions to prioritize the most relevant type, rather than order the choices alphabetically

Tags: visual-studio-code

When programming with Visual Studio Code, it seems like the autocompletion simply orders the choices alphabetically without thinking much of the type. For example:

[image]

It will prioritize the integer option, but 95% of the times I will end up wanting the string option instead.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio Code to order the suggestions so that the first options are the most contextually-relevant? For example, take into account the type of an assignment or the type of a method parameter.

Comment: By default, Visual Studio Code only has simple auto-complete. Do you have an appropriate extension installed for whatever language you’re trying to use?

Comment: @DanielB, well, I have Omnisharp for C#, but it doesn't seem to do anything particularly special about auto-completion, and I'm unaware of any extension that focuses on this matter